# Tangle file when exporting

Tags: elisp, org-mode

I want to call `org-babel-tangle` every time an export is executed.

I've tried (without success) just add the new command to `org-latex-pdf-process` or using an export filter (`org-export-filter-final-output-functions`).

first attempt:

```
(add-to-list 'org-export-filter-final-output-functions 'org-babel-tangle)
```

second attempt:

```
(add-to-list 'org-latex-pdf-process 'org-babel-tangle)
```

It seems that `org-babel-tangle` cannot be used as it is, maybe it is returning something that is not expected by `add-to-list`. However, my limited knowledge of elisp does not allow me to identify what is wrong.

Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add it (or actually a small wrapper function around it) to `org-export-before-processing-hook`. I have not tested this but it should work:

```
(add-to-list 'org-export-before-processing-hook (lambda (be) (org-babel-tangle)))
```

The functions called by this hook are passed a single argument, the backend, but we ignore it in this case.